# Problem with WordPress restore using cPanel and WP Toolkit

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, cpanel, whm, wptoolkit

I have just installed WP Toolkit in cPanel / WHM and am looking to restore a WordPress site exported from cPanel on another server.

A friend was given a cPanel backup, ending `.tar.gz`, and an SQL DB backup, ending `.sql.gz`.

I have successfully restored the database, and I uploaded the tar using File Manager in cPanel.

But when I navigate to WP Toolkit, that file does not appear in the backup list, even though it appears to be pointing at the right folder on the server.

I am thinking that the site must correspond directly somehow to the WP installation on this server. This is a pain because it took an hour to upload!

I tried expanding the gz, but it is still not visible.

Given that I have this file, how can I recreate the site from it? I am currently trying "Restore a Home Directory Backup" in the Backup page, but that means uploading the file again, so I won't know til morning!

I thought a cPanel backup was entirely portable and could be moved from server to server?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have imported the SQL DB and website files in the file manager and extracted the website files. However, were you able to configure the SQL DB and the `wp-config.php` file?

The `wp-config.php` contains your website configuration in the database; ensure that you have connected it.

To test if the website files are connected, you can simply go to `https://example.com` and check if you can see the site:

- If yes, that means you don't have to worry about the database connection.
- If not, and you're getting a database connection error, check the source that I provided below for steps on how you can configure the database in your `wp-config.php`.

source: https://help.vodien.com/articles/change-database-configuration-in-wordpress/

In addition, you need to make sure that the domain `example.com` is pointing to the correct server where you have uploaded the files.

Alternatively, you can go to `https://example.com/wp-admin` to edit, update, or manage the WordPress site.

Comment: I hope that you find this information useful.

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvoting my answer if you feel it was useful to you. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)